# How to access contents of Object If I don't know the structure in c#?

Tags: c#

I have an object and I don't know its structure until runtime. So is there any way to access data from the object ?

Thanks.

PS: I can't think of any other details to provide, please ask me if this isn't enough!

Comment: When you say an object, do you mean a class object or some binary data for which you don't know anything about its structure?

Comment: @Raj, Hi, I mean a Class Object, I will have the class in Var o, and I know that the o is object, i need to access its contents!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do with with reflection. For example:

```
public static void ShowProperties(object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Null: no properties");
        return;
    }
    Type type = o.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
                                        | BindingFlags.Instance);
    // Potentially put more filtering in here
    foreach (var property in properties.Where
                 (p => p.CanRead && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(o, null));
    }
}
```

Look at the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) API for ways to get methods, events, fields, nested types etc.

Comment: Hi, i am able to access the properties of objects this way, but I wanted to know the actual values of its members. thanks

Comment: @iamserious: Properties *are* members, and that's displaying the values. If you want to get the fields, call `GetFields` instead - although then you'll presumably want to get *private* fields, which means you'll need a higher trust level. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to determine what properties, methods, and fields an object has.  take a look at the methods on the `Type` type